# C++ Network Programming with Active Directory

Tags: c++

i seeking for a way to get from the active directory via 
username the full path of the user network drive, in c++.

dose anybody know function that will help me with this ?

thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Take a look into [ADSI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa772170%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), as it a set of COM interfaces, this is easily useable in a C++ application.

This [link](http://www.codeguru.com/forum/showthread.php?t=309450) shows a sample of getting the username, so it shouldn't be a huge leap to get other information on the user.